# Get link and href text from html doc with Nokogiri & Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to use the nokogiri gem to extract all the urls on the page as well their link text and store the link text and url in a hash.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href=#foo>Foo</a>
        <a href=#bar>Bar </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to return

```
{"Foo" => "#foo", "Bar" => "#bar"}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
Hash[doc.xpath('//a[@href]').map {|link| [link.text.strip, link["href"]]}]

#=> {"Foo"=>"#foo", "Bar"=>"#bar"}
```

Split up a bit to be arguably more readable:

```
h = {}
doc.xpath('//a[@href]').each do |link|
  h[link.text.strip] = link['href']
end
puts h

#=> {"Foo"=>"#foo", "Bar"=>"#bar"}
```

Comment: You can replace `link.attributes['href'].value` with just [`link['href']`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: Tip: In Ruby 2.1, instead of `Hash[...]` append `.to_h`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
h = doc.css('a[href]').each_with_object({}) { |n, h| h[n.text.strip] = n['href'] }
# yields {"Foo"=>"#foo", "Bar"=>"#bar"}
```

And if you're worried that you might have the same text linking to different things then you collect the `href`s in arrays:

```
h = doc.css('a[href]').each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ]}) { |n, h| h[n.text.strip] << n['href'] }
# yields {"Foo"=>["#foo"], "Bar"=>["#bar"]}
```

Comment: The problem with the `a` tag is that it can be used for links and non-links like named anchors. You have to check for the presence of the `href` attribute.

Comment: @Mark: I think I switched to `a[href]` while you were commenting just for that reason.