# How do I access the "href" parameter for a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get link and href text from html doc with Nokogiri & Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336039/get-link-and-href-text-from-html-doc-with-nokogiri-ruby)

I'm getting the following Nokogiri output:

```
obj =  [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x19b1418 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x123dd44 name="href" value="http://sample.com">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x123c408 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1201f24 name="class" value="highlight">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1143b64 "Web">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x113a9c4 "Sample Text">]>]
```

How can I get the value `"http://sample.com"`? I tried `obj.attributes("value")` but had no luck.

I appreciate any help.

I'm using:

- rails 3.2.x
- nokogiri

Comment: You need to provide sample HTML and show the code you wrote that's creating `obj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<a href="http://sample.com">
<span class="highlight">Web</span>
</a>
Sample text
EOT
obj = doc.search('a')

obj.first['href']
=> "http://sample.com"
```

If there's only one `<a>` tag in the document, you could simplify the code using `at`:

```
obj = doc.at('a')['href']
```

would return the same value.

Comment: It's interesting that it worked, hasn't been accepted, and got a down vote.